# What is my exact URI for my Google Cloud Bucket?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-storage, restful-url

I want to upload a picture to my Google Cloud Storage Bucket from my ios Application. I am using a http post method to add the picture. However, I want to know the exact URI to use in my code for a http Post method because Google Documentation uses so many and is unclear to the exactness. If the name of my bucket is test1212test what is the exact URI?

Answer (score 1):

See [Request URIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-uris) - any of the following should work:

```
test1212test.storage.googleapis.com
storage.googleapis.com/test1212test
storage-upload.googleapis.com/test1212test
test1212test.storage-upload.googleapis.com
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not what I was looking for. That is what is in the Google Documentation however it did not work because my objective was to upload a picture straight from my phone to the google bucket. So instead, in my python API I returned a uploadURL generated by the blobstore and sent it to my iOS app and used that exact upload url and it worked.

In Python API:

```
USER_BUCKET = '%s-%d-%s-%d' % (first, age, email, now)

        my_upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload',
                                                 gs_bucket_name=USER_BUCKET)
```

I made then a unique bucket name, then I created their unique upload URL.

In iOS app:

```
    NSString *uploadUrl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"uploadUrl"];
//This is your version
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[manager POST:uploadUrl parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image);
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"testImages" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The uploadUrl is what was created in Python and I just saved it to the users NSUsersDefaults.